# How do I use a like in a join with SQL92?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a like in a join statement. My reason I have one field that is a varchar and another that is also a varchar however, the second field is a comma separated list.

```
SELECT c.Class, c.SubClass, c.Value, c.Pairs, c.Description, prodt.ProductType, p.Type
FROM pub.table1 c 
INNER JOIN pub.Table2 p ON c.SubClass like CONCAT(CONCAT('%',p.Type),'%')
INNER JOIN pub.Table3 prodt ON p.ProdType = prodt.ProductType  
WHERE c.Class = 'whatever'
```

In this case p.Type is the comma separated list and the SubClass is the normal varchar.

I have tried using a few different things already. I would have thought the below worked, but it did not.

```
INNER JOIN pub.Table2 p ON c.SubClass like '%' + p.Type +'%'
```

Is there a way to do this or do i have do something different like another select with SQL92? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is this tagged "ansi-sql-92"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see a SQL92 tag so I went with that one too.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma-separated values to begin wih.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`. There is a much easier (and better) solution in Postgres that doesn't require `LIKE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The database I am using is an progress/openedge one. While I 100% agree you should never use a comma separated list as a value, I have to work with what i was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your explanation, you need to swap the `LIKE` since `p.Type` contains the list of values.

```
p.Type like '%' + c.SubClass + '%'
```

Your code:

```
SELECT c.Class, c.SubClass, c.Value, c.Pairs, c.Description, prodt.ProductType, p.Type
FROM pub.table1 c 
INNER JOIN pub.Table2 p ON p.Type like '%' || c.SubClass || '% '
INNER JOIN pub.Table3 prodt ON p.ProdType = prodt.ProductType  
WHERE c.Class = 'whatever'
```

Here's a sample test to show this:

```
select 'matched'
where 'abc' like '%abc,def,ghi,jkl%'

select 'matched'
where 'abc,def,ghi,jkl' like '%abc%'
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that looks like " Syntax error in SQL statement at or about "+ c.SubClass + '%' INNER JOIN pub.Table3"

Comment: You posted an incorrect code snippet. If you use what i have in my answer you won't get that.

Comment: In standard SQL, `||` is used to concatenate strings. `+` is used to add numbers

Comment: Thank you, I must have had a typo or something. I copied your snippet and it seemed to work. I no longer have that error but I do have a different one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name cpy that, i just didn't find it relevant to the core question'

Comment: @scsimon It cannot find the column prodt.ProductType.

Comment: @AnthonyFastcar you had that in your original query... but that would mean that `pub.Table3` doesn't have a column named `ProductType`

Comment: @scsimon it definitely exisit. i would post a picture but it wont let me.

Comment: Then I can't tell you what's going on without seeing your actual query and the DDL of the tables.

Comment: @scsimon that's fair. Thank you for all your help so far though! This is what I was looking for and i will continue looking into my current error.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want something like this:

```
ON ',' || p.type || ',' like '%,' || c.subsclass || ',%'
```

`||` has been the string concatenation operator in ISO/ANSI SQL for a long time.  To be honest, I don't remember if the adoption of this operator dates back 26 years.

Comment: `||` was part of the SQL-86 standard